# Setting parameters dynamically for PreparedStatements

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am curious, can we just enter parameter dynamically? For example, I have an object like:

```
class Fields {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  public Fields(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  //Getter - setter here
}
```

Now, I prepare statement for:

```
public void main() {
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.PrepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND name = ?");`
}
```

then I set

`Fields param = new Fields(2, "xxx");`

Well.. call me lazy, how can I send param to PrepareStatement like

`ps.setParameters(param)`

or maybe:

`ps.setParameters(param.getAsArray())`

To illustrate my point better, I want to make something like:

```
for (Fields f: fieldList) {
  sql += f + " = ?";
}
```

pardon my missing "AND" / "OR" operator for above codes. My ultimate goal, is so that I can create the whole fields and respective parameters by passing entity class by filling only partial field. The code will then skip null fields and put filled fields as parameter.

Well, just for curiosity.

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK you are limited with regard to what you can pass to a `PreparedStatement`.  Typically, just the types which you use in a database query are allowed, e.g. int, varchar, blob, etc.  What is the `Fields` class?

Comment: The fields class as above would be limited to a String and therefore not very useful.  Also in you had a join and the same variable would re-used, the same Field object could not be re-used.  Of course you could extend from `PreparedStatement` and implement this yourself.

Comment: Added information to illustrate my point better. 
In short, I want to dynamically create criteria clause from entity object, and pass my fields and parameters from entity object. But that is not only limited in entity, I could create some specific class and partially fill relevant fields, skip unneeded ones, and pass them to prepareStatement.

Comment: You will need to use Hibernate or another library that wraps JDBC, or write that yourself. There is nothing in a `PreparedStatement` itself that supports what you want.

Comment: I do not know if you have to use a `PreparedStatement` but if it's not required you could use the Java Persistence Query and use positional parameters.  Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html

Comment: It means I have to use Hibernate or something. As I said, it is too heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. this is a very crude solution. I still don't like the fact that I have to reiterate all fields twice to get field's type String or otherwise, but feel free to refine it further since this is still very crude. Also, you need to extend those ps.setSomething() parameter below before ps.setObject() failsafe. You also need to anticipate query without any criteria, like skipping those criteria object scanning and go straight to execute. But I hope you get the idea.

```
public static String addPrefix(String prefix, String field) {
    return new StringBuilder(prefix)
            .append(Character.toUpperCase(field.charAt(0)))
            .append(field.substring(1))
            .toString();
}

public static <T> List<T> query(Connection conn, T criteria, String operator) throws SQLException {
    List<T> list = null;
    Class<?> targetClass = criteria.getClass();
    if (targetClass.getAnnotation(Table.class) == null) throw new SQLException("ERROR: Table not defined at entity class " + targetClass.getName());
    StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM ").append(targetClass.getAnnotation(Table.class).name());
    List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getAnnotation(Column.class) == null) continue;
                Method m = targetClass.getMethod(addPrefix("get", field.getName()).toString());
                Object o = m.invoke(criteria);

                if (o == null) continue;

                if (parameters.isEmpty()) SQL.append(" WHERE"); else SQL.append(operator);
                SQL.append(" ").append(field.getAnnotation(Column.class).name()).append(" = ?");
                parameters.add(o);
        }

        try (Connection connection = IwiPrivate.getInstance().getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL.toString())) {
                Integer x = 1;
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    String type = field.getType().getName();
                    Method m = targetClass.getMethod(addPrefix("get", field.getName()));
                    Object o = m.invoke(criteria);

                    if (o == null) continue;
                    if (type ==  "java.lang.String") ps.setString(x, (String) parameters.get(x));
                    else if (type == "java.lang.Integer") ps.setInt(x, (Integer) parameters.get(x));
                    else ps.setObject(x, parameters.get(x)); //Put more set traps here.
                }
                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
                    while (rs.next())
                        list.add((T) Database.mapSingle(rs, targetClass));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(QueryExperiment.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now, to use it, simply create your entity object like this

```
@Table(name = "testTable")
public class Entity {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then put it as criteria

```
public void testQuery() {
    Entity criteria = new Entity();
    criteria.setId(7777);
    try (Connection connection = yourDatabase.getConnection()) {
        List<Entity> assets = QueryTest.query(connection, criteria, "AND");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IwiPrivateTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

It will create an SQL like:
`SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE id = ?`
and send 7777 as parameter using setInt

If you want to avoid ORM and create simple queries, I believe this method works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly put the values in the parameters without the **Field** class.

```
ps.setParameters(2, "xxx");
```

Try these, hope it will work to you.

```
    Field field1 = new Field(0,1,"id");
    Field field2 = new Field(1,"Nathan","name");

    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(field1);
    fields.add(field2);

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ");

    // Dynamically Construct your SQL Query String
    for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.size() ; i++) {
        String strTemp = " AND ";
        String strTempEquals = " = ?";
        if(fields.size()-1 == i) {
            strTemp = ";";
        }
        strBuilder.append(fields.get(i).getColumnName());
        strBuilder.append(strTempEquals);
        strBuilder.append(strTemp);
    }

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.PrepareStatement(strBuilder);

    // Dynamically pass your values from your Field class to the parameters of PreparedStatement
    for (Field tempField : fields) {
        ps.setParameter(tempField.getIndex(),tempField.getValue());
    }
```

I made some changes in your **Field** class.

```
class Field {
private Integer index;
private Object value;
private String columnName;

// Constructor
//Getters and Setter
}
```

Comment: In fact, I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use parameterized constructor like this i hope this what you need

```
class Fields {
private Integer id;
private String name;
 public Fields(int id,String name)
 {
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    setParameter();
 }
 public  void setParameter()
 {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.PrepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND name = ?");
    ps.setInt(1,id);
    ps.setString(2,name);
 }
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, I don't want to specify setSomething() for each parameter.

Comment: ohh than u should go through hibernate/spring

Comment: Spring is too heavy, and it can't take criteria directly from Entity;

Comment: right.. if u find solutions of your query than please share

Answer (score 1):

In Java code, using spring jdbc also we can achieve this.

An example code is below for reference: For now, we are updating 100 parameters in loop. if we know number of parameters, then we do this.
If your requisite is that of a table which has 100 parameters, then you can follow below approach as well with some modifications.

```
  public Class MappingDTO{
     private String attribute1;
     private String attribute2;
     private String attribute3;
     private String attribute4;
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     private String attribute100;

     public getAttribute1(){
     return attribute1;
     }
     .
     .
     .
     public getAttribute100(){
     return attribute1;
     }
```

}

```
  updated=jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("our query", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                        @Override
                        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int index) throws SQLException {
                                        MappingDTO mappingDTO = mappingDTOList.get(index);
                                        Class<?> tClass = mappingDTO.getClass();
                                        int i=1;
                                        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { //100 max attributes can be updated //dynamic preparestatemetn setter
                                            Method method=null;
                                            try {
                                                method = tClass.getMethod("getAttribute"+(i), new Class[] {});
                                            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                                                LOG.error("Exception thrown | uploadStatementTemporaryTableUpdate | No such method exception | while trying to find methods", e);
                                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                                LOG.error("Exception thrown | uploadStatementTemporaryTableUpdate |Security Exception | while trying to find methods", e);
                                            }
                                            String str1=null;
                                            try {
                                                str1 = (String)method.invoke(mappingDTO, new Object[] {});
                                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

                                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

                                            }
                                            ps.setString(i, str1);

                                        }


                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public int getBatchSize() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        return mappingDTOList.size();
                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

PreparedStatement has a [setObject(int, java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object)) method. You could use that within a a class or method that accepts array/list of Fields and appends names to the sql and sets parameters using setObject method.

Keep in mind that this approach is highly vulnerable to sql injection attacks so use it with caution.

Comment: Hmm... that gives me some idea.. hold on. I''ll give something soon.

Comment: The real question to me is why do you need this? Why not create POJO classes that correspond to your tables and read/write the POJO objects to/from the corresponding tables?

Comment: As I said, I don't use any ORM. JPA or Hibernate or anything. I just don't like them. They are too heavy, and they are lacking optimizations. Therefore I prefer to optimize from database server. All I need are simple retrieval from views or stored procedures. But this question was just a simple experiment which can speed up my work, but still light on resources.